# How to use Python proxy server when getting [Errno 111] Connection refuse

Tags: python, django, proxy, odoo, odoo-10

I try to test [Odoo Web Service API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html) from Python and everything works fine from localhost using a basic Django app and xmlrpclib. But when I [host it](http://geko.pythonanywhere.com/odooapp) at pythonanywhere I get a *[Errno 111] Connection refused* error:

[image]

On their help page [they describe](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/) that ports are closed on free accounts and that their HTTP proxy at **proxy.server:3128** has to be used. How to do that?

Actually it should work without the proxy once the add *.odoo.com* to their [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/), but the proxy issue is interesting for me also to know how to run this app on a different hosting.

Here is the Django code of my view (yes I know that's bad practice to put html in the view, just for testing):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import xmlrpclib

url = "https://demo3.odoo.com"
db = "demo_100_1489044950"
username = "admin"
password = "admin"

#odoo service connection
common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
products = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'product.template', 'search_read',
    [[]],
    {'fields': ['name', 'list_price'], 'limit': 10})

for product in products:
    print product['id'], product['name'], product['list_price']

def index(request):
    html = "<html><body><h1>Odoo Products</h1>"
    for product in products:
        name = product['name'].encode("utf-8", "strict")
        html += "<div>"+name+": "+str(product['list_price'])+"</div>"
    html += "</body></html>"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

ps: Source code of Django app is in [this github repository](https://github.com/geraldo/odooapi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](https://www.boriel.com/en/2006/01/19/xml-rpc-a-traves-de-un-proxy/) explains how you can create a subclass of `xmlrpclib.ServerProxy` that's proxy-aware, which should work fine.  (Caveat: it looks entirely correct to me but I haven't tried it myself.)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that worked. I hope it's ok that I added a code example to your answer.

Comment: It's OK as far as I'm concerned, but it looks like the moderators would prefer the code example to be part of a comment rather than an edit.

Comment: No problem, the code is in the github repo so should be easy to find for interested ppl.